# How to modify a subset of data without using variables

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash, ramda.js

Using functional Javascript like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), [Lodhash](https://lodash.com/), [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/), [Immutable JS](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js), if I have some (semi-accurate) data like this:

```
var data = {
  people: [
    {name: 'Vishwanathan Anand', age: 46},
    {name: 'Garry Kasparov', age: 52},
    {name: 'Magnus Carlsen', age: 25},
  ],
  computers: [
    {name: 'Deep Blue', age: 26},
    {name: 'Deep Fritz', age: 21},
    {name: 'Deep Thought', age: 28},
  ]
}
```

I wish to transform it to

```
var data = {
  people: [
    {name: 'Vishwanathan Anand', age: 46, rank: 0},
    {name: 'Garry Kasparov', age: 52, rank: 1},
    {name: 'Magnus Carlsen', age: 25, rank 2},
  ],
  computers: [
    {name: 'Deep Blue', age: 26},
    {name: 'Deep Fritz', age: 21},
    {name: 'Deep Thought', age: 28},
  ]
}
```

*Note how only the `people` substructure got `rank`*.

I know I can,

```
_.extend({
  computers: _.map(data.people, (p, i) => {
    p.rank = i;
    return p;
  })}, {
    computers: data.computers
  })
```

But what if I need to do this without using any variables (no more access to `data`!) using underscore's `chain`?

Something like

```
_.chain(data).subset('people').map((p, i) => {
  p.rank = i;
  return p;
})
```

**NOTE** This is a real problem and not a matter of convenience. I am working on a project that involves creating a sort of environment for functional operators and ***variables*** are not allowed.

It seems Underscore and the like operate on the ***entire*** structure (Array / List). is there any way I can ask it to operate on a substructure while preserving the rest?

Comment: how about `_.each(data.people, (p,i)=>{ p.rank=i })`. But that's mutation, that's very very evil in Functional Programming ;)

Comment: @Thomas exactly! The function is no longer pure. How can we do this for more complex examples and without `each`?

Comment: "variables are not allowed" doesn't really make a lot of sense. Without variables, you can't even use functions, and without functions, you can't do anything.

Comment: I think what you are looking for are lenses.

Comment: @Bergi. Checked. Lenses aren't ideal for this use case. I dont exactly mean  I can't use variables, more like I can't use variables more than once and I can't use any temporary variables. I am working in a GUI like environment in a kind of "flow programming" model. Won't make much sense in a traditional programming environment but I have a special case here :)

Comment: @GauravRamanan: How are lenses not ideal?

Comment: @Bergi I am looking at Lenses at RamdaJS. Maybe you can give an answer to the data I mentioned above? I think I'd understand an example more than anything. Plus, i can upvote and Tick :)

Comment: I guess it would be something like `propertyLens("people")(ps => ps.map((p, i) => (p.rank=i,p)))(data)`

Comment: @GauravRamanan, you initial example already mutates the values. how about this: `_.mapObject(data, (v,k) => k === 'computers'? _.map(v, (p,i)=>_.extend({rank:i}, p)): v );` (still underscore) no mutation, but therefore you lose identity for the objects in computers.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit unpleasant but it works for this case.

```
_.chain(data)
    .mapObject((value, key) => {
        if (key==='people') {
            return value.map((p,i) => _.extend(p, {rank: i}));
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    })
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ramda you can use [R.evolve](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) to create a function, that accepts a key and an callback (`cb`), and maps the items of key to the required form:

```js
const { evolve, addIndex, map } = R

const mapPart = (cb, key) => evolve({
  [key]: addIndex(map)(cb)
})

const data = {"people":[{"name":"Vishwanathan Anand","age":46},{"name":"Garry Kasparov","age":52},{"name":"Magnus Carlsen","age":25}],"computers":[{"name":"Deep Blue","age":26},{"name":"Deep Fritz","age":21},{"name":"Deep Thought","age":28}]}

const result = mapPart((o, rank) => ({ ...o, rank }), 'people')(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```